# How to pass string from php to js

Tags: javascript, php

For example i have test.php thats receiving some data based on GET method.
Result is defined as string, for example $kript.
Now i need to pass that specific string value to external js file (main.js) to use it as data insessionStorage.
PHP:

How to i pass php string value to external js?

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["token"]) && isset($_GET["r"]))
{
    $token = $_GET["token"];
    $r = $_GET["r"];
    $kript = 'r='. $r .';token=' . $token;

}
?>
```

Comment: Use AJAX and echo JSON.

Comment: Or you can simply `echo $kript;`. That will be the response text to the AJAX request.

Comment: There are many tutorials on using AJAX between JS and PHP, you should read one.

Comment: The problem is that i'm calling that main.js in same test.php for some results which are based on this string value.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. You don't call JS from PHP. JS runs on the client, PHP runs on the server. If you want more help, post the main.js code.

Comment: In main.js i have this where i need this value from php string from test.php: window.onload = () => {
 sessionStorage.setItem('sport-data', JSON.stringify({
  "subpage": null,
  "autologoutTime": null,
  "username": null,
  "cashId": null,
  "tCashId": null,
  "lang": "en",
  "topBarMode": 1,
  "logoUrl": null,
  "country": {"name":"en","code":"en"},
  "layout": 0,
  "credits": null,
  "theme": "theme2",
  "headerHeight": 20,
  "footerHeight": 0,
  "fullscreen": null,
  "sbGameView": null,
  "parentNavMenu": 0,
  "data": {
   stoken: "VALUE FROM $KRIPT"
  }
 }))
 chan...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i got it.
All i needed to do in test.php is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">var stoken2 = "<?= $kript ?>";</script
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And in main.js i can use stoken2 as value of $kript from php.